# Usage of a variable within a Comparator<Monster> that is passed to a PriorityQueue

Tags: java

I have a `PriorityQueue<Monster> pq` which stores a Monster's HP (health) and the healing (heal) done to it. `heal` stores the value of `healing_tracker` at the time of the creation of the Monster object.

Within the driver class, `healing_tracker` tracks the total healing done to my Monsters throughout the game. For example, let's say `healing_tracker` has a value of 50, and when I create a new Monster with 30 HP, `Monster bob = new Monster (30, healing_tracker)` , bob.heal would be 50. Should I heal my Monsters by another 50, bob.heal would not change, however `healing_tracker` updates to 100.

The way I want to sort my Monsters in my PriorityQueue is in ascending order of net HP. For a Monster, charlie, it's net HP would be: `charlie.health - charlie.heal + healing_tracker`. Therefore, I created a Comparator to do so, but I realized that I couldn't pass `healing_tracker` as a parameter into the Comparator.

Is there a way to use `healing_tracker` which I established in the driver class such that it updates the Comparator?

Comment: Can't you implement ```compareTo()``` from the interface ```Comparable``` (or ```Comparable<Monster>```) within the Monster class? I guess you keep the ```healing_tracker``` as a variable within the Monster, so you could access it within the ```compareTo()``` in Monster

Comment: You could create a comparator class that takes a reference to a mutable healing_tracker object in the constructor and stores it and uses it in the compare() method. However, I suspect that every time you change the healing tracker value, you'd have to remove and re-add all monsters to the queue, as they wouldn't automatically be re-ordered.

Comment: Yes, one exception was that we could not individually update healing_tracker as the question indicated that it would take too long!

Comment: @TeoJunXiong Please [edit] your question to include the source codes of your classes. After that explain where you want to keep a sorted list/queue and what you want to do with it. It looks like you want to add objects to a sorted container but change the values of these objects after you have added them to the container. This will break the internal storage structure of the container. Maybe you have to keep the objects sorted by yourself, either with a normal `sort()` call (implementing the interfaces required) or by using a custom data structure. Please elaborate on what you want to do.